# Is there a standard naming convention for implementations of interfaces that seem standard/default?

Tags: interface, naming-conventions

Trying to code to an interface so that unit testing and design are better. Some things that I am coding doesn't seem to have any other implementation other than the obvious one. Is there a naming convention for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've only got one implementation, why not name your interface after it?  You can always refactor the name later, if a second implementation comes along.

Most of the time, we do name our interfaces after the implementation that inspired them.  If we then find that we get a second implementation of that interface, we'll either rename the original implementation to be more specific or rename the interface to be more general.

Comment: Sort of like this. IFoo, Foo? Feels strange but I have done it this way. Thanks